# Flex : Create new folder in zip file

Tags: apache-flex, flex4

I am using Flex, Flash Builder 4.5 and Extension Builder 2.0.0 and I use the "[nochump ziplib](http://nochump.com/blog/archives/15)"  library to generate a ZIP file. I want to create a new folder in created ZIP file, but I can't find such function function in the "nochump" library. 
 Can anyone please tell me if there is any function to add new folder in a ZIP file or a library which can help me do this?

Answer (score 2):

**The directories are not first-class citizens in the ZIP format.**

The archive is built from "entries" - plain **files** with their relative locations to the "central directory" (the "root" of the archive). This means that the ZIP file is composed from entries like "pictures/1.jpg", "doc/old/1.txt" etc. You don't have separate entries for the "pictures", "doc" or "doc/old" directories.

**You can't create a new directory directly.** Instead of creating a new directory first (such as "newDir") you may want to create a file (entry) inside instead (such as "newDir/1.txt") and "newDir" will appear as directory when you open the resulting ZIP file.

**If you insist on having an empty directory in the archive, you may try the hacky way** - adding entries like "newDir/." with zero length. But this may not work with your library.

The [Wikipedia article for the ZIP format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_%28file_format%29) has all the theory explained pretty well.